is there any visual i power bi marketplace which has the capability to perform given task
suggest me the power bi visual where we can do conditional formatting over table where the row containg string "total" should be bold
and next row to this bold row should be empty and should have a line ,exolre power bi visual marketplace and suggest any visual
